# Console print value detail on the List

Tags: flutter

I have class `Student` and List  like below

```
List<Student> info;
class Student {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  Student({this.id, this.name});
}
```

and I have some code to add value to List

```
for (var v; v < count; v++) {
              info.add(Student(
                id: ....,
                name: ....,
              ));
            }
```

How can I console print detail of value on `List<Student> info` for test?

Answer (score 0):

Override `toString` of `Student` class to make it return the String you want:

```dart
class Student {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  Student({this.id, this.name});

  @override
  String toString() => 'id: $id, name: $name';
}
```

Then print the list with `print(info)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this

```
print(info.toString());
```

to print the whole list.

Comment: Just so you know, this won't work if the ```toString()``` method is not implemented on the ```info``` object, it will print the memory address, good luck debugging with that.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I hadn't realized that... thanks!